# Arduino to PC communication

Tags: arduino, connection, arduino-uno

i want to send some text which holds some data, like a (.txt) file from an Arduino mega to a PC or to a website through internet is this possible ? and how to do that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Sending data from one place to another is exactly the kind of thing computers do. If you want a more specific answer, you'll have to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Arduino has already developed a HTTPClient https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient for making HTTP calls over the internet from Arduinos which may work for you. Using this client you should have no problem sending plain text, arrays of data, or files themselves over the internet.

If you are not familiar with making or consuming HTTP Requests, I'd suggest you look into that for more information, but your likely looking to make a POST or PUT request.

Comment: so i wanted to ask something more, this method works for sending data only or i can receive some text that i can manipulate and use it in my program as a variable name maybe or something like that